# Unable to use indicator variables in alerts in tradingview

Tags: tradingview-api

I am using the indicator "(Hoss) VWAP AD" in trading view and would like to set up a custom alert.
I would like to have an alert which provides the value of the indicator variable "Basis".

But unfortunately, it's not working. When the alert is getting executed, the variable won't get resolved.

What I am doing wrong?

Thank you very much

Alert message:
{{close}}, {{time}}, {{plot_0}}, {{plot('Basis')}}

[image]
[image]

```
//@version=5
indicator('[Hoss] VWAP Deviation', overlay=true)

ls = input(false, title='Log-space', group = "Optional")
type = 'Average Deviation'
length = input(60, group="Strategy Modification")
source = input(close, group="Strategy Modification")
_low = ls == true ? math.log(low) : low
_high = ls == true ? math.log(high) : high
src = ls == true ? math.log(source) : source

//weighted mean
pine_vwmean(x, y) =>
    cw = 0
    cd = 0.0
    w_sum = 0.0
    d_sum = 0.0
    for i = 0 to y - 1 by 1
        cd = x[i]
        cw = volume[i]
        d_sum += cw * cd
        w_sum += cw
        w_sum
    d_sum / w_sum

//weighted standard deviation
pine_vwstdev(x, y, b) =>
    d_sum = 0.0
    w_sum = 0.0
    cd = 0.0
    for i = 0 to y - 1 by 1
        cd = x[i]
        cw = volume[i]
        d_sum += cw * math.pow(cd - b, 2)
        w_sum += cw
        w_sum
    math.sqrt(d_sum / w_sum)

//weighted average deviation
pine_vwavdev(x, y, b) =>
    d_sum = 0.0
    w_sum = 0.0
    cd = 0.0
    for i = 0 to y - 1 by 1
        cd = x[i]
        cw = volume[i]
        d_sum += cw * math.abs(cd - b)
        w_sum += cw
        w_sum
    d_sum / w_sum

vwmean = pine_vwmean(src, length)

//consider using Average Deviation instead of Standard Deviatio if there are values outside of 3rd upper & lower bands within a rolling window
dev = if type == 'Standard Deviation'
    dev = pine_vwstdev(src, length, vwmean)
    dev
else if type == 'Average Deviation'
    dev = pine_vwavdev(src, length, vwmean)
    dev


plot(ls == true ? math.exp(vwmean) : vwmean, color=color.new(#b7b7b7, 60), title='Basis')

fill(plot1=plot(ls == true ? math.exp(vwmean + dev * 2) : vwmean + dev * 2, color=color.new(#B20000, 0), title='Upper dev 2'), plot2=plot(ls == true ? math.exp(vwmean + dev * 3) : vwmean + dev * 3, color=color.new(#FF6666, 0), title='Upper dev 3', display=display.none), color=color.new(#FF4D4D, 80), title='Upper band', transp=0)
fill(plot1=plot(ls == true ? math.exp(vwmean - dev * 3) : vwmean - dev * 3, color=color.new(#00CC00, 0), title='Lower dev 3', display=display.none), plot2=plot(ls == true ? math.exp(vwmean - dev * 2) : vwmean - dev * 2, color=color.new(#008000, 0), title='Lower dev 2'), color=color.new(#006600, 80), title='Lower band', transp=0)

// Input to enable or disable the table visibility
table_visible = input(false, title="Show Table", group="Deviation Cross Monitor")
// Input for the number of candles to look back
table_length = input(300, title="Table Lookback Length", group="Deviation Cross Monitor")

// Custom count function
count_occurrences(cond, length) =>
    count = 0
    for i = 0 to length - 1
        if cond[i]
            count := count + 1
    count

// Count occurrences of prices above Upper dev 2 and below Lower dev 2
upper_dev_2 = vwmean + dev * 2
lower_dev_2 = vwmean - dev * 2
above_upper_dev_2 = count_occurrences(close > upper_dev_2, table_length)
below_lower_dev_2 = count_occurrences(close < lower_dev_2, table_length)

// Create table in the bottom right corner
var table tbl = table.new(position=position.bottom_right, rows=2, columns=2)

if table_visible
    if barstate.islast
        // Update the table headers
        table.cell(tbl, 0, 0, "Above Upper Dev 2", bgcolor=color.gray, text_color=color.white)
        table.cell(tbl, 0, 1, "Below Lower Dev 2", bgcolor=color.gray, text_color=color.white)
        
        // Update the table values
        table.cell(tbl, 1, 0, str.tostring(above_upper_dev_2), bgcolor=color.new(color.green, 90), text_color=color.green)
        table.cell(tbl, 1, 1, str.tostring(below_lower_dev_2), bgcolor=color.new(color.red, 90), text_color=color.red)
else
    table.delete(tbl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try :

```
{{close}}, {{time}}, {{plot_0}}, {{Basis}}
```

This doesn't work directly from the creating alert window (perhaps a bug).

A workaround is to create a alert in your code (at the end of it) and then, use the windows alert and choose your indicator as condition, give a name the this alert, and let the message as is ( it will be ({{plot_0}}) ).

To create the alert in your code :

```
alertcondition(condition=true, title="Volume alert", message="({{plot_0}})")
```

NB : In my example, the condition=true for the alertcondition, of course, use the condition what suit you the best.

Then create your alert on your graph :
[image]

After the bar close, if the condition is true in your code, you will see the value of Basis :
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Just tried it. Same outcome. Returns "27519.86, 2023-03-26T07:12:00Z, {{plot_0}}, {{Basis}}"

Comment: @Tobi it is hard to answer you without your pinescript. Can you update your question and insert your code ?

Comment: Thanks. I just uploaded the pinescript.

Comment: @Tobi I update my answer, let me now if its solve your problem.